# How to make a polygon change it's height depending on the amount of text that needs to fit in there in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've been trying to make a chat like UI in python using Tkinter. I've made some progress but for some reason, the height of my polygon isn't changing enough to fit the whole text. After a few lines the text overspills outside of the polygon, usually after 3 or 4. I've tried various things to get it to work, but it still doesn't? I would like the polygon to be able to change size depending on the amount of text that is inside, width wise it works, but height wise it doesn't? Could anyone help me figure out why and how to fix it? Any suggestions is helpful? Also? Feel free to give me any advice/help on how to make my code better and more efficient?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.config(bg="lightblue")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600,bg="grey")
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)

bubbles = []

def round_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius=25, **kwargs):
        points = [x1+radius, y1,
                  x1+radius, y1,
                  x2-radius, y1,
                  x2-radius, y1,
                  x2, y1,
                  x2, y1+radius,
                  x2, y1+radius,
                  x2, y2-radius,
                  x2, y2-radius,
                  x2, y2,
                  x2-radius, y2,
                  x2-radius, y2,
                  1+radius, y2,
                  x1+radius, y2,
                  x1, y2,
                  x1, y2-radius,
                  x1, y2-radius,
                  x1, y1+radius,
                  x1, y1+radius,
                  x1, y1]

        return canvas.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)
    

class RoundBubble:
    def __init__(self,master,message=""):
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = canvas
        resize = canvas.create_text(15, 15, text=message, width=300, anchor="w")
        x, y, w, h = canvas.bbox(resize)
        self.chonk = round_rectangle(x-5, y-5, x+w, y+h, radius=25, fill="light blue")
        canvas.move(self.chonk, 0, 530)
        self.canvas.tag_lower(self.chonk)
        canvas.move(resize, 0, 530)
        root.update_idletasks()

def send_message():
    
    if bubbles:
        canvas.move(ALL, 0, -50)
    a = RoundBubble(canvas,message=entry.get())
    bubbles.append(a)

entry = Entry(root,width=26)
entry.grid(row=1,column=0)
Button(root,text="Send",command=send_message).grid(row=1,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

I've tried using len() and splitlines() to count the number of lines to adjust for the height but that didn't seem to work?

Comment: `Canvas.bbox` will return coords that wrap around a polygon.

Comment: @Derek , I've tried that, but it didn't work. It wasn't enough, it only works for 2 lines of text and then it overspills.

Comment: Have you tried setting `width`?

Comment: @Derek Yes, I have. Still doesn't work? Could you please review my code?

Comment: `canvas.bbox` works on single line and multi line text, even when text is rotated with `angle`. I've added a vertical scrollbar and can see a potential problem in the way you scroll the text/rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `.bbox()` returns the coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right corners of the bounding box, so the line

```py
self.chonk = round_rectangle(x-5, y-5, x+w, y+h, radius=25, fill="light blue")
```

should be as below instead:

```py
self.chonk = round_rectangle(x-5, y-5, w+5, h+5, radius=25, fill="light blue")
```

Note that you can simply create the bubble just below the bottom of the canvas and then move all messages up by the height (and some vertical space) of the newly created bubble.  Also suggest to put the function `round_rectangle()` inside the `RoundBubble` class:

```py
...
class RoundBubble:
    def __init__(self, master, message=""):
        self.canvas = master
        # create the text and bubble at the position just below the viewable area
        resize = self.canvas.create_text(15, self.canvas.winfo_height()+5, text=message, width=300, anchor="nw")
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.bbox(resize)
        self.chonk = self.round_rectangle(x1-5, y1-5, x2+5, y2+5, radius=25, fill="light blue")
        self.canvas.tag_lower(self.chonk)
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        # move all messages up to see the just added message
        self.canvas.move(ALL, 0, -(y2-y1+10)-10)

    def round_rectangle(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, radius=25, **kwargs):
        points = [x1+radius, y1,
                  x1+radius, y1,
                  x2-radius, y1,
                  x2-radius, y1,
                  x2, y1,
                  x2, y1+radius,
                  x2, y1+radius,
                  x2, y2-radius,
                  x2, y2-radius,
                  x2, y2,
                  x2-radius, y2,
                  x2-radius, y2,
                  1+radius, y2,
                  x1+radius, y2,
                  x1, y2,
                  x1, y2-radius,
                  x1, y2-radius,
                  x1, y1+radius,
                  x1, y1+radius,
                  x1, y1]

        return self.canvas.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)


def send_message():
    a = RoundBubble(canvas, message=entry.get())
    bubbles.append(a)
...
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, I really appreciate it!! I didn't realize that was the issue the whole time, lol, my bad :/ . Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. I really appreciate it!! This has been very helpful!! And, I'll definitely take your suggestions. Thanks, Have a great day x

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution that adds a `Scrollbar` and a `scrollregion` to canvas then keeps track of the location of each bubble and uses that to calculate the next message position. I've used `tags` to move both text and bubble together. Scrolling messages is performed by supplying `canvas.yview_scroll` with location data.

```
root = Tk()
root.config(bg="lightblue")

canvas = Canvas(
    root, width = 600, height = 600,
    xscrollincrement = 1, yscrollincrement = 1,
    bg = "grey", scrollregion = "0 0 600 4000")
canvas.grid(columnspan=2, sticky = "nsew")

vert = Scrollbar(root, orient = "vertical", command = canvas.yview)
vert.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = "ns")
canvas["yscrollcommand"] = vert.set

bubbles = []
location = [15]

def round_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius=25, **kwargs):
    points = [x1+radius, y1,
          x1+radius, y1,
          x2-radius, y1,
          x2-radius, y1,
          x2, y1,
          x2, y1+radius,
          x2, y1+radius,
          x2, y2-radius,
          x2, y2-radius,
          x2, y2,
          x2-radius, y2,
          x2-radius, y2,
          1+radius, y2,
          x1+radius, y2,
          x1, y2,
          x1, y2-radius,
          x1, y2-radius,
          x1, y1+radius,
          x1, y1+radius,
          x1, y1]

    return canvas.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)
  

class RoundBubble:

  def __init__(self,master,message=""):
    self.master = master
    self.canvas = canvas
    
    text = canvas.create_text(
        15, location[~0], text=message,width=300, anchor="nw", tags = "A")
    x, y, w, h = canvas.bbox(text)
    chonk = round_rectangle(
        x-5, y-5, w+5, h+5, radius=25, fill="light blue", tags = "A")

    x1, y1, w1, h1 = canvas.bbox(chonk)

    location.append(h1 + 5)

    self.canvas.tag_lower(chonk, text)
    self.canvas.dtag("A")


def send_message(e = None):

    if len(location) > 1:
        canvas.yview_scroll(location[1]- location[0], "units")

    a = RoundBubble(canvas,message=entry.get())
    bubbles.append(a)
  
entry = Entry(root,width=26)
entry.grid(row=1,column=0)
entry.bind("<Return>", send_message)
Button(root,text="Send",command=send_message).grid(row=1,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for the taking to time to help me out, I really appreciate it!! It means a lot. I've tried it, and it works great!! Thank you so much!! Have a great day!! xx